# Equivalent of outer join with non-equals predicate in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, join, linq-to-sql, outer-join

I am looking for the Linq-equivalent of the following SQL:

```
SELECT t0.Fk_CompanyId, t0.CheckedUtc, t0.IsBlocking
  FROM MyTable t0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable t1
    ON t0.Fk_CompanyId = t1.Fk_CompanyId AND t0.CheckedUtc < t1.CheckedUtc
 WHERE t1.Fk_CompanyId IS NULL
   AND t0.CheckedUtc IS NOT NULL
```

The closest I've got with Linq is:

```
from t0 in MyTable
join t1 in MyTable on t0.Fk_CompanyId equals t1.Fk_CompanyId into t1tmp
from t1 in t1tmp.DefaultIfEmpty()
where t1.Fk_CompanyId == null && t0.CheckedUtc != null && t0.CheckedUtc < t1.CheckedUtc
select new { cid = t0.Fk_CompanyId, cuct = t0.CheckedUtc, isbl = t0.IsBlocking }
```

... which produces the following SQL (reformatted slightly):

```
SELECT t0.Fk_CompanyId, t0.CheckedUtc, t0.IsBlocking
  FROM MyTable AS t0
  LEFT OUTER JOIN MyTable AS t1
    ON t0.Fk_CompanyId = t1.Fk_CompanyId
 WHERE (t1.Fk_CompanyId IS NULL)
   AND (t0.CheckedUtc IS NOT NULL)
   AND (t0.CheckedUtc < t1.CheckedUtc)
```

These are not exactly equivalent. (The `t0.CheckedUtc < t1.CheckedUtc` is pushed to the `WHERE`.) When I outer-left-join on `t0.CheckedUtc < t1.CheckedUtc`, this produces NULL values on the right-hand-side of the join. When I filter with `WHERE` instead, this removes all the NULL values that I am interested in.

Perspective: I am trying to find the rows in *MyTable* with the most recent *CheckedUtc*, if there are any non-NULL ones, grouped by *Fk_CompanyId*. And I want one row for each *Fk_CompanyId*. There are several "possible duplicates" that only deal with *finding the most recent CheckedUtc*s (but not their respective rows), or assume that *CheckedUtc* is NOT NULL.

So: **How do I perform the equivalent of a join on a non-equals predicate in Linq?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
from t0 in MyTable
From t1 in MyTable( x=>x.Fk_CompanyId=t0.Fk_CompanyId && x.CheckedUtc > t0.CheckedUtc ).DefaultIfEmpty()
where t1.Fk_CompanyId == null && t0.CheckedUtc != null 
select new { cid = t0.Fk_CompanyId, cuct = t0.CheckedUtc, isbl = t0.IsBlocking }
```

Comment: Thank you, @MukeshKalgude!!! So the trick is to place the join condition inside the `.Where()` clause of the table being joined.

Comment: I don't understand what you say

Comment: I'm sorry, never mind. LINQPad is playing tricks on me. I'll delete my comment.